# Why was I shocked while touching an outlet phase and a cement wall at the same time?

Tags: electrical-engineering

My question is, if I touch the outlet phase wire with one hand and the cement wall with the other hand, will I get shocked?

I knew that I'll be shocked in this case, even happened to me once, but we had the same conversation in class like two days ago, I've told the teacher what happened to me, he laughed and shortly the whole class started laughing at me, even calling me names. Could someone please validate what I was saying or if not offer me an alternative explanation as to why did I get shocked?

Comment: No, but it is still dangerous. For example, you said nothing from the ground, or the wall can be moisty.

Comment: If the cement in the wall is sufficiently conductive that a current of several milliamps or more can flow (Physics), then your body will be affected by the current (mostly Biology).

Answer (score 1):

This will of course depend on the configuration of the cement wall; Namely how well is it coupled to the ground and hence the earth? Is there any insulation between the cement wall and the ground?

If the insulation is poor or non-existent you *will* get a shock as your electrical potential is (much) higher than that of the ground. Electrons will flow from the outlet phase, through your body (dissipating energy as it does, inflicting harm on your body) and through the ground and then earth (as the earth is considered electrically neutral on its large scale). The discharge of electricity through the earth *will* electrocute you.

Comment: Thanks alot guys for the quick and detailed answers, now I can prove the teacher that I was right, even if it will do (for sure), more harm than good :P Thanks again.

Comment: Well, feel free to give your teacher my regards, and tell him I said he's an incompetent fool, for the way he seems to conduct his class more so than for his lack of understanding of electricity. You *never* shame a student for his/her answer no matter how incorrect, nor would any real teacher allow one of his students to be shamed by fellow students.

Answer (score 1):

You will get shocked even if you are otherwise perfectly insulated, simply due to the fact that your own body acts as a capacitor. Oh, and you did not get "electrocuted", otherwise you would not be here to tell your story.